# GTK Touchpad Event - Scrolling - How to control/stop it

Tags: gtk, signal-handling

I have a GtkTextView which is scrollable and I have a GtkButton which sets the view back to the selected line in that GtkTextView.

When I scroll down in the textview via my touchpad with a two finger gesture and press than immediately that button, the view is set to the selected line but due to the gesture (scrolling movement) was not finished, the textview gets scrolled down again.

How can I stop that gesture or signal?

I already tried [gdk_event_get](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Events.html#gdk-event-get) and [gdk_event_free](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Events.html#gdk-event-free) but without success.

Any advise is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: What function do you use to scroll back to the selected line?

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/187

Comment: I used/tried gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark or gtk_text_view_scroll_to_iter

Comment: This issue posted above is exactly my problem. But kinetic scrolling is not enabled by default. Even when I set it to false with gtk_scrolled_window_set_kinetic_scrolling right after initiating the window it is always there. Now I also tried to turn it of as first call when I click the button but the movement from scroll action is still ongoing. Any idea? Thx.

Comment: Hi! As a side note, for scrolling in GtkTextView it's generally better to use gtk_text_view_scroll_to_mark. You can read more here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-scroll-to-iter

Comment: Sorry I had an error while copying gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark what should be gtk_text_view_scroll_to_mark. The behavior is the same.

Comment: Ah, and I use GTK version 3.18.9

Comment: Ok, I think you can either open a new issue or comment on the one linked above, as you wish.

Comment: I found https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEventControllerScroll.html#GtkEventControllerScroll-struct Sadly it is not in 3.18.9 Maybe this could be used to stop the scrolling?

Comment: I also tried gdk_event_new with GDK_TOUCH_CANCEL and GDK_TOUCH_END and use gdk_event_put to set it at first queue position. But sadly not working for me (https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Events.html#gdk-event-put). Any idea what could be done to get that scroll event and stop it?

Comment: Mmm, I don't know. Sorry